# Why can't we use * on non-pointers?

Tags: c

Let's say I have the code:

```c
int x = 5;
int* p = &x;
```

then writing `*p` will return 5 and allow me to modify `x` (as expected). Say, for whatever reason that I then write:

```c
int y = p;      // y holds x's address 
*y = 3;         // this is invalid and throws an error when compiling
*((int*)y) = 3; // this is okay
```

(when compiling on gcc 9.2)

My question is: why does C not allow us to use `*` on non-pointer types?

Comment: The `*` is a pointer indirection (dereference) operator.  What would it do with non-pointers?

Comment: `int` is not meant to hold pointers, and there is no guarantee that you can safely convert pointers to and from `int`.  Your "okay" code is not okay, it is at best implementation-defined behavior and will fail badly on many implementations.

Comment: Why would it?  The point of pointer types is that it's explicit that it refers to a memory address that can be dereferenced.  Certainly you could shove any value into an int and then try to dereference it as a pointer, but you would have to cast it first.  C prevents you from doing that accidentally (to some extent).

Comment: How should the compiler distinguish a valid integer from a pointer address if it did what  you suggests?

Comment: Sounds like an xy question, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I assumed that `*` just returns the memory contents at the value saved at the pointer, but I now realise that isn't the case.

Comment: @DavidRanieri I wasn't trying to achieve anything, just understand why. I do realise that this is bad code - but I was wondering why it wasn't allowed.

Comment: @talbi, it does return the contents of the memory at that location, but you would need to be explicit and write `* (int *) y = 3`, and many decades ago people often did that sort of thing.  But it is not valid to assume that an `int` is large enough to hold the value of an `int *`, so the assignment `y = (int) p` may lose information.  In that case `* (int *)y` may be attempting to dereference an invalid memory location.  This sort of thing should be avoided.

Comment: `int` is assumed to hold a number. You *can* tell the compiler it is holding an address and try dereferencing it, as you did in your last statement. But note, you told the compiler not only that it is an address, you also told it which type of data this address is expected to hold. This is not something the compiler can infer from the `*` operator only.

Comment: C's parent language, called B, did allow unary `*` on integer values. B was a typeless language that operated on machine words, not on typed objects and values. If you applied `*` to an expression, the compiler would simply assume that it held a pointer value. C is far more strict about consistent use of types (but less so than some other languages).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C is a strongly typed language, which means that the operations which are allowed on an object (and the interpretation of those operations) is a function of the object's type.  That's literally what it means for an object to have a type: the type determines the operations you can do with the object.

Unary `*` (the pointer indirection operator) is defined for pointer types, and it's not defined for integer types.

If you want to treat an integer's value as if it were a pointer, you can use an explicit cast, as in the `*((int *)y) = 3;` example you mentioned in your question.

There are two reasons the unary `*` operator is *not* defined for integers:

1. Taking an integer and pretending it's a pointer is generally a bad idea, not something to be encouraged.  If you really want to do it, the extra cost imposed on you -- namely that you have to use that pointer cast -- is appropriate.
2. The bare expression `*y` doesn't contain enough information to know how big the pointed-to object might be.  If you write `*y = 3` and it *were* legal, how would the compiler know to assign an `int`, a `short`, or a `char`?

Point 2 is key.  It's important to remember that C does not have one "pointer" type.  Every pointer type incorporates a specification of the type of object which the pointer will point to.  That's no accident, it's fundamental, and there's no way around it.

So you can't implicitly treat an integer as if it were a pointer, and even if you do it explicitly -- that is, with a cast, as in `*((int *)y) = 3`, you may still be on shaky ground, especially if integers and pointers don't have the same size on your machine.

These days, this is all generally such a bad idea that the compilers are slowly dropping their old "the programmer must know what he's doing" attitude, and getting somewhat hissy with warnings.  For example, `int y = p` will generally get you a warning about a pointer-to-int assignment, and even with the explicit cast, `*((int *)y) = 3` might get you a warning about "cast to pointer from integer of different size".

Answer (score 1):

Boring answer - because that's how the language is defined:

> **6.5.3.2 Address and indirection operators**
> **Constraints**
> 1 The operand of the unary `&` operator shall be either a function designator, the result of a
> `[]` or unary `*` operator, or an lvalue that designates an object that is not a bit-field and is
> not declared with the `register` storage-class specifier.
> 2 ***The operand of the unary `*` operator shall have pointer type.***

<sup>*[C 2011 Online Draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)*</sup>

Slightly-less boring answer:

Pointers are not integers; they do not behave like integers.  The operations on pointers and integers are different.  While there is such a thing as pointer arithmetic, it does not behave like integer arithmetic.  Pointers are *abstractions* of memory addresses, which do not have to have integer representation.

Type *matters* in C (not as much as in some other languages, but it does matter).  Operations on integer types do not apply to pointer types and vice versa, just like operations on aggregate (`struct` or array types) do not apply to integer types.

You can't use `*` on an integer operand for the same reason you can't use `[]` or `()` or `.` or `->` on an integer operand; those operations are not defined for integer types.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that we can't use * on integer because pointer and integer both are different.
you can not use int y to store address because integer can,t hold addresses it can only take integer value.

```
int y = p;      // y holds x's address 
*y = 3;         // this is invalid and throws an error when compiling
*((int*)y) = 3; // this is okay
```

On the other hand pointer are designed to store address of variable so you can use * to access the value store at that address while integer can not store address.
operations for both integer and pointer are different from each other

Answer (score -1):

`*((int*)y) = 3; // this is okay` No, this is not ok, it causes UB. Just because the compiler does not complain does not mean the code is ok or is free from UB.